# How do i install ddev on Digital ocean

Tags: digital-ocean, ddev

Digital ocean has a simple way to setup Ubuntu 16.0 which comes with docker 17.10 and docker-compose 1.1.

However, due to some issues with 17.10, you might have issues working with, but ddev can still run very well on docker 17.10, just to avoid future issues, you can follow the steps in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Digital ocean wont cost you much to set up, it comes with free 100 USD credit and spinning a new server cost  0.003/hour

To start

1. Register on Digital ocean
2. Create a new droplet(select Ubuntu 16.04), like i said in the question above, you can decide to follow one-click app installation which comes with docker && docker-compose but with old versio, but they still met the ddev requirements.

[Digital ocean; how to install ddev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te8GX.png)

3. Your login credentials will be sent to your email
4. your new droplet comes with fresh Ubuntu installation and you can proceed to install docker, docker-compose and ddev

Installing docker
To install docker [follow this doc to have latest docker on your machine](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

Installing docker compose
To install docker compose [follow this doc.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

Finally
Install ddev by [following official ddev documentation](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: So why install ddev on a server?

Comment: @rfay I think there is a missing piece on ddev, or at least I could not find in the docs, which is how you do the jump into production? Maybe use swarm with the autogenerated docker compose file? Kubernetes?

Comment: DDEV-Local isn't (currently) integrated with any production capabilities. git is the deployment technique for code, live db development would be assumed to be done upstream of (hopefully not) with copied databases. There's not intent for the ddev containers to be used in production.